# Programmatically edit IIS IPGrant Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've been working on a programmatic solution to edit the IPGrant table in IIS.

As it stands, I can View the IPGrant list Correctly, and CAN add to it.

However, I cannot remove or replace items in the IPGrant list.

MSDN and such recommend that you write (the values of the old list + the new value) to the List, however I'm finding I'm getting a HResult of "Cannot create file with that name, file already exists".
Adding to the list only works for me If I pass in the new value only.

After some reading:

```
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/59731.aspx
http://www.aspdev.org/articles/web.config/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/iiswmi.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/iiswmi.aspx?msg=1739049
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/0001/01/01/400749.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524322%28VS.90%29.aspx
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33215307/setting-ip-restrictions-in-iis-7.aspx
```

I'm finding that there is a compatability issue with IIS 7/6 and using the Metabase - in that one can only add to it, not remove.

Is there a more current method for IIS 7/7.5 that can be used (in c# please) to administrate the IPGrant table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft.Web.Administration, or AppCmd, or Javascript (COM - AHADMIN) to do that, here are a few examples on how to remove:

```
private static void Main() {

    using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
        Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

        ConfigurationSection ipSecuritySection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/ipSecurity");

        ConfigurationElementCollection ipSecurityCollection = ipSecuritySection.GetCollection();

        ConfigurationElement addElement = FindElement(ipSecurityCollection, "add", "ipAddress", @"169.132.124.234", "subnetMask", @"255.255.255.255", "domainName", @"");
        if (addElement == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not found!");

        ipSecurityCollection.Remove(addElement);

        serverManager.CommitChanges();
    }
}

private static ConfigurationElement FindElement(ConfigurationElementCollection collection, string elementTagName, params string[] keyValues) {
    foreach (ConfigurationElement element in collection) {
        if (String.Equals(element.ElementTagName, elementTagName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            bool matches = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < keyValues.Length; i += 2) {
                object o = element.GetAttributeValue(keyValues[i]);
                string value = null;
                if (o != null) {
                    value = o.ToString();
                }

                if (!String.Equals(value, keyValues[i + 1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    matches = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (matches) {
                return element;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using Javascript:

var adminManager = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager');
adminManager.CommitPath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST";

var ipSecuritySection = adminManager.GetAdminSection("system.webServer/security/ipSecurity", "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST");

var ipSecurityCollection = ipSecuritySection.Collection;

var addElementPos = FindElement(ipSecurityCollection, "add", ["ipAddress", "169.132.124.234","subnetMask", "255.255.255.255","domainName", ""]);
if (addElementPos == -1) throw "Element not found!";

ipSecurityCollection.DeleteElement(addElementPos);

adminManager.CommitChanges();

function FindElement(collection, elementTagName, valuesToMatch) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++) {
        var element = collection.Item(i);

```
    if (element.Name == elementTagName) {
        var matches = true;
        for (var iVal = 0; iVal < valuesToMatch.length; iVal += 2) {
            var property = element.GetPropertyByName(valuesToMatch[iVal]);
            var value = property.Value;
            if (value != null) {
                value = value.toString();
            }
            if (value != valuesToMatch[iVal + 1]) {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matches) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

return -1;
```

}

And Finally AppCmd.exe:
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /-"[ipAddress='169.132.124.234',subnetMask='255.255.255.255',domainName='']" /commit:apphost